# Mutation Solution for JavaScript Algorithm Challenge

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mutation

I'm trying to solve the JavaScript Basic Algorithm Scripting Mutation exercise, and I've come across an issue.

The following code is my trial at a solution. However, it doesn't satisfy three out of the nine tests given

```
function mutation(arr) {
  // two arrays of index values zero and one
  //all arrays must be set to lowercase first
  var first=arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var second=arr[1].toLowerCase();
  //iterate through arrays
  for(i=0; i<second.length; i++){
    if(arr[0].indexOf(first.length) && arr[0].charAt(first.length) !== arr[1].indexOf(second.length) && arr[1].charAt(second.length)){ 
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
mutation(["hello", "hey"]);

//
```

The following tests are what IS satisfied by my attempt at a solution.

mutation`(["hello", "Hello"])` should return true.
mutation`(["zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", "qrstu"])` should return true.
mutation`(["Mary", "Army"])` should return true.
mutation`(["Mary", "Aarmy"])` should return true.
mutation`(["Alien", "line"])` should return true.
mutation`(["floor", "for"])` should return true.

The following tests are what is NOT satisfied by my attempt at a solution

mutation`(["hello", "neo"])` should return false.
mutation`(["voodoo", "no"])` should return false.

Can you show me what is wrong in my code? Thanks so much!

Comment: your for loop only ever runs once ... because you `return` either true or false in the first iteration

Comment: you're also using `indexOf` completely wrong - which is why you're always getting "true" as a result

Comment: @JaromandaX, interesting in regards to the first comment, but how I'm I using `indexOf` completely wrong, can you explain?

Comment: look up documentation ... I doubt you want to indexOf(length of first word) ... why are you looking for a number in a text string?

Comment: looks like you want to do `var mutation = ([f, s]) => [...s.toLowerCase()].every(c => [...f.toLowerCase()].includes(c));`

Comment: @JaromandaX, I like this better: 

`for(i=0; i<second.length; i++){
      // var letter of second array
      var letter = second[i];
      //notification 
      var alerter = first.indexOf(letter);
      //notification for if character/substring is not found in particular string..which is value of -1
      if (alerter ===-1){
        return false; 
      }    
  }
  return true;
}
`

Comment: you may well like it better, why isn't that the code you use, rather than the clearly wrong code in the question?

Comment: @JaromandaX, because I found that out later lol